# array in c and struct

Tags: c

I don't understand why this program print "*klmnop*" and not just "*klm*".
b is an array of size 2!
This is the code:

```
struct S
{
  int i1;
  int i2;
  char b[2];
};

int main()
{
  char a[] = "abcdefghijklmnop";

  struct S* s = a + 2;
  printf("[%s]\n" , s->b);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You realize that this code is UB in a system where `sizeof(int)` is 8 bytes? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a disaster from the standard-compliance point of view, with the implicit conversion from `char *` to `struct S *` with no real guarantee of alignment. But I think the point was clear enough. It could have just been `printf("[%s]\n", a+10)` though. It looks like a reduced form of a larger, non-hypothetical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `printf("[%s]\n" , s->b);` prints the data from the address s->b to the character `'\0'`. after the address `s->b` whenever it will find the `'\0'` it will print the data.

```
char b[2];
```

above statement do not include `'\0'` at the last character so it will continue reading the data from the address untill it find String terminator `'\0'`

Comment: I think you mean character `\0`

Answer (score 5):

Like most string functions, your printf doesn't have any information about the size of the array that the string is contained in. It only has a pointer to a single char, and your promise that this char is the first in a sequence of chars terminated by `'\0'`. When asked to print the whole string, it'll keep going until it finds that terminator or crashes, whichever comes first.